# How to mosaic multiple raster datasets?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

I have more than 50 raster files. I have used to mosaic to new raster tool on Arcgis and I wonder if there's anyway I can select all rasters instead of having to click one by one to add them up.

Comment: You could try not mosaicing but creating a mosaic dataset https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000003p000000 instead, mosaic datasets are a lightweight object which builds reasonably quickly but the best part is you can tell it to load all the images in a folder *and all subfolders* which is a real time saver; You get a chance to modify the overlaps and colour balance the images before committing then use copy raster https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000094000000 to export your final mosaic when you're happy with the result.

Comment: what would be the real difference between mosaic dataset and mosaic to new raster?

Comment: A mosaic dataset references the existing images, mosaic to new raster combines the existing images into a new raster. The downside of a mosaic dataset is that you can't move (easily) the rasters that it is referencing, the upside is it takes very little extra space for the overviews and you can color balance and modify seam lines, for example if one image as a cloud but another doesn't you can trim the cloudy part, another example is adjusting the edge of the overlap to follow a road or river so that the rasters aren't blocky. Rasters in a mosaic dataset do not need to have the same cell size.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options you can use to accelerate the process of adding raster images to the input rasters list to mosaic:

1. Select the first raster in the input raster of mosaic tool to add to it the raster
   list, then keep pressing the downwards arrow button <kbd>↓</kbd> on
   your keyboard to add the rest of rasters until the end.
2. Use the browse button to navigate to the folder to select all rasters from the folder, assuming that all rasters are located in the same folder. If not, then use the first option. This is the fastest I know.